# how to pass csrf token in angular form while calling laravel post API

Tags: php, laravel-5, angular2-forms, angular2-services

i have created 2 folder one having angular code and another folder for laravel api.
I have created one form in angular and need to post data in laravel to save the result but how to send csrf token value via angular while submitting form .